# When to use zero-variant enum over unit-like struct

Tags: rust, struct, types, enums

If I understand correctly rust [unit-like structs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/structs.html#structs) can be used like say [atoms in Erlang](https://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#atom).

But I don't understand what [zero-variant enums](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/enumerations.html#zero-variant-enums) provide. Could someone explain what the main purpose of zero-variant enums is and in which cases they might be favored over unit-like structs?

Comment: The reason why they are used is because enums without variants can not be constructed, but structs without fields can.

Comment: The unit type `()` has a single value. All values of that type are the same. Zero-variant enums have no value at all.

Comment: That's the point I don't understand. What is the use for a type that can't be constructed or have values?

Answer (score 4):

One usage for zero-variants enum is to express unreachable code. For example, an infallible [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) or [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/trait.FromStr.html). This commonly occurs when using generics. Here's an example: [`OnceCell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/unsync/struct.OnceCell.html) has both [`get_or_init()`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/unsync/struct.OnceCell.html#method.get_or_init) and [`get_or_try_init()`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/unsync/struct.OnceCell.html#method.get_or_try_init) methods.

```rust
enum Void {}
match self.get_or_try_init(|| Ok::<T, Void>(f())) {
    Ok(val) => val,
    Err(void) => match void {},
}
```

To save code duplication, [the `get_or_init()` method calls `get_or_try_init()`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/1.16.0/src/once_cell/lib.rs.html#555). However, without using empty enums, this would incur cost at runtime because of the panic for the impossible `Err` case if the `get_or_try_init()` call isn't inlined). This is intended to be replaced by [the never type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.never.html) once stabilized. Using empty enums has two advantages over unit structs:

1. They cannot be constructed by mistake.
2. They can hint the optimizer that this code is unreachable and allow it to remove it. They can also help the developers avoid panics in the code, because an infallible enum may be converted into the never type by `match value {}`, and the never type may be coerced into any other type. An example is in the `once_cell` code above.

Another usage is in generics, when you need only a type and not value, for example in [the Strategy pattern](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/patterns/behavioural/strategy.html) at compile time, some people prefer zero variants enums to express that this types are not meant to be instantiated.